# How to halt process only when something like "No Internet" or "Network Error" occurs while downloading images using requests

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, python-imaging-library, urllib

I have written a script to download and save the images in a directory from the urls provided. It uses the `requests` to access the URL given in a `DataFrame` (CSV file) and download the images in my directory using `PILLOW`. NAme of the image is the index number of that url in my CSV. If there is any bad url, which is not accessible, it just increases the counter. It starts downloading from the maximum index to desired index everytime I run the script.  My code is working fine. It is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sys

from PIL import Image

import requests
from io import BytesIO

import argparse


arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=True, description='Download images from url in a directory',)

arg_parser.add_argument('-d','--DIR',required=True,
                       help='Directory name where images will be saved')

arg_parser.add_argument('-c','--CSV',required=True,
                       help='CSV file name which contains the URLs')

arg_parser.add_argument('-i','--index',type=int,
                       help='Index number of column which contain the urls')

arg_parser.add_argument('-e','--end',type=int,
                       help='How many images to download')

args = vars(arg_parser.parse_args())


def load_save_image_from_url(url,OUT_DIR,img_name):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    img_format = url.split('.')[-1]
    img_name = img_name+'.'+img_format
    img.save(OUT_DIR+img_name)
    return None


csv = args['CSV']
DIR = args['DIR']

ind = 0
if args.get('index'):
    ind = args['index']

df = pd.read_csv(csv) # read csv
indices = [int(f.split('.')[0]) for f in listdir(DIR) if isfile(join(DIR, f))] # get existing images

total_images_already = len(indices)
print(f'There are already {len(indices)} images present in the directory -{DIR}-\n')
start = 0
if len(indices):
    start = max(indices)+1 # set strating index
    
end = 5000 # next n numbers of images to download
if args.get('end'):
    end = args['end']

print(f'Downloaded a total of {total_images_already} images upto index: {start-1}. Downloading the next {end} images from -{csv}-\n')

count = 0
for i in range(start, start+end):
    if count%250==0:
        print(f"Total {total_images_already+count} images downloaded in directory. {end-count} remaining from the current defined\n")

    url = df.iloc[i,ind]
    try:
        load_save_image_from_url(url,DIR,str(i))
        count+=1

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.exit("Forced exit prompted by User: Quitting....")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at index {i}: {e}\n")
        pass
```

I want to add a functioning that when there is something like `No internet` or `connection error` occurs, instead of going forward, it stops the process for say 5 minutes. After 5 tries i.e 25 minutes, if the problem still persists, it should quit the program instead of increasing the counter. I want to add this because if there is no internet for say even 2 minutes, and comes again, it'll run through the loop and start downloading the images from that index. Next time if I run this program, it'll think that the missing URL were bad but there was just no internet connection.

How can I do this?

**Note: Obviously, I am thinking about using `time.sleep()` but I want to know which error directly reflects `No Internet` or `Connection Error` in `requests`? One is `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError`**
If I have to use this, how can I use this to keep trying on the same `i` counter until 5 attempts and then if unsuccessful, quit the program and on successful connection, run the regular loop.

Comment: Use `time.sleep()`

Comment: Obviously I can use `time.sleep()`. I want to know which is the error which reflects `No internet` or `connection error` as there might be lots of erros in `requests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than sleep is to use exponential backoff.

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=3,
    status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    method_whitelist=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

response = http.get(url)
```

Here, you can configure the parameters as follows:

1. total=3 - The total number of retry attempts to make.
2. backoff_factor - It allows you to change how long the processes will sleep between failed requests

The formula for back-off factor is as follows:
`{backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of total retries} - 1))`

So backoff of 10s will be
5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560 - these are the sleep times between subsequent requests

Comment: So I want to try on the same request until say, 20 minutes and then use `sys.exit(No network. Tried for 25 minutes. Now exiting`)` but if it goes well, I want the program to run smoothly to the next iteration. How Can I use something like this. I am updating the new code with multiple `except` blocks that I have used.

Comment: The code raises an exception if it goes above number of requests. You can wrap it in `try/except`

Comment: Yeah so it is what I want to know . I mean where in my code should add this? Inside `load_save_image()` function or  inside the loop where I have all of my `try-multiple_except`?  Also, How can I use specifically the `ConnectionError` with your code?

Comment: The above code is an adaptor. You need to change the `requests.get` to `http.get` using the above code. As you already have wrapped it in a `try/except` block. I don't think any more changes are needed

Comment: Though I have no idea about how that works, but will do that for sure LOL!. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I was once using google APIs and I occasionally used to get no-internet, error423, or something like of that sort. 
I kept my whole code in the *try* block and in the *except* block I applied *.sleep()* for X-seconds. 
In this way I didn't had to search the error type

> To be noted, before doing it, make sure your code doesn't has any other type of error and will run smoothly, unless encounters with “No Internet” or “Network Error”

#### This was my approach to the issue

```py
import libs
basic operations
try:
  block 1
  block 2
  block_where_error_occurs
  block 3

except:
  print("Network error") 
  time.sleep(X-Seconds)
```

I hope this helps you too. Let me know if this approach doesn't serves your purpose.